# What is a good recentish book on numerical algorithms for stiff non-linear PDEs?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, stochastic-pde

The title pretty much says it all. The equations I am looking at are non-periodic with both finite and semi-infinite time horizons. Non-onerous licensing (if there are code snippets) is a plus.

Books which go beyond the techniques described in Boyd 2000 (http://perso.uclouvain.be/alphonse.magnus/num1a/boyd01.pdf) would be great, although that is a good example of the sort of book I am looking for.

Comment: Trefethen has a textbook about finite difference methods for numerically solving PDEs: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/pdetext.html

Comment: Thanks! This book is on the old side and the recommendations (at least what has been completed) are not as sophisticated as those in the Boyd book mentioned above.

Comment: Are you familiar with Strikwerda? How do you like the Strikwerda book?

Comment: Not very- from the TOC it seems to examine the stability issues in depth, so I will have a look.

Comment: One of the best books I read on stability is by Hairer & Wanner, 'Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II: Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems'. It's probably older than what you are looking for but nevertheless it's a great book.